# Pretest posttest regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, repeated-measures

I am trying to set up a multiple regression for a pretest posttest dependent variable. There will be no control group, and we will be controlling for age (continuous) and gender. Want to use the regression rather than an ANCOVA due to the small sample of the study.

The interest is in the within groups test to see if the treatment (which happened between time 0 and time 1). I would like to set up the model in the following way:

Score = b0 + b1 (time) + b2 (age) + b3 (gender)

So that way scores at time 0 would be the pretest score and at time 1 would be the posttest score.

Not sure if this model would be valid (I am sure it violates some assumption). Does someone know if this can be modeled this way? (A citation which says it is possible to model it this way or of a study that uses this model would be amazing, if it is possible) Or a good pretest posttest regression alternative which can measure the difference from time 0 to time 1?

Answer (score 1):

Why not model like this:

$$\Delta\text{Score} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{\text{time}}\text{time} + \beta_{\text{age}}\text{age} + \beta_{\text{sex}}\text{sex} + \varepsilon$$

Since presumably you are interested in *change* in score?

Comment: I am pretty sure that way we would have to remove time though, since time would not make a difference if both pretest and posttest are included to calculate the change in the score. I wanted to use time so we could use the time coefficient to see the effect of the treatment. Would it be possible to use the significance of the intercept in the change score model you have there (without time) in order to see if the treatment is effective?

Comment: @user56066 Is *time* simple an indicator of pre/post? Also: without a control group of some form (no treat, best standard treat, placebo) you **cannot estimate *effect* of treatment** because you do not know whether *Score* was going to increase , remain constant or decrease anyway.

Comment: Yes, apparently i can't just say yes since that is less than 15 characters